# Events between an ASPX and ASCX

Tags: asp.net, .net, events, ascx

i'm a beginner in .NET, and search since yesterday morning to resolve my problem without finding the solution.

Here is my problem :

I create dynamically some User Controls by this way, because I need to give parameters :

```
List<ANNOUNCEMENT> listAnnouncement = getAnnoucements();
foreach(ANNOUNCEMENT ann in listAnnouncement)
{
    if(ann.IS_CURRENT_ANNOUNCEMENT && currentAnnouncement == null)
    {
         currentAnnouncement = ann;
    }
    List<Object> listParams = new List<Object>();
    listParams.Add(ann);
    AnnouncementPresentation ap = (AnnouncementPresentation)(Controller.LoadControl(Page, "~/UserControls/AnnouncementPresentation.ascx", listParams.ToArray()));
    /* important for the end of the method */
    ap.modifyAnnouncementButtonClick += new EventHandler(modifyAnnouncementButtonClick);
    pnl_announcements.Controls.Add(ap);
}
```

In this ASCX, I have a button, and when user will click on it, I want to call a method contained in my ASPX, so I do this in the ASCX :

```
public event EventHandler modifyAnnouncementButtonClick;
protected void btn_modify_announcement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PageAdminAnnonces.currentAnnouncement = annonce;
    modifyAnnouncementButtonClick(sender, e);
}
```

And this in the ASPX :

```
protected void modifyAnnouncementButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     initListOfAnnouncement();
     lbl_errors.Text = currentAnnouncement.TITLE;
}
```

I think everything works, but there is the problem : It works once, and at the end of the method, I delete my ASCX as you can see, and create new ASCX. But they don't have the methods, and when I click again, nothing works, so the ASPX is reloaded. After reloading, it works again.

Do i do something wrong?

Comment: It seems that you're adding dynamically created controls in  `initListOfAnnouncement` method, which is a little late in the page's lifecycle. I would suggest you to add all the controls you need inside `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` method.

Comment: I'm adding these controls in Page_Load, my method initListOfAnnouncement() is called in Page_Load. The problem is, when I have a click, I need to change my User Controls (to put one of them with text in bold for example), but without loading all the page, because if I do that I'll lost all my parameters, and lose what UserControl have to be in bold. I don't know if my explanations are clear enough.

Comment: I still suggest you to **create the controls in `Page_Load` and NOT delete/recreate them in click handling event, but only set  properties of existing controls there**. If you need some additional parameters in `Page_Load`, I suppose you can pass some additional parameters to the page i.e. by passing them in query string using `Button.PostBackUrl` property.

Comment: So, if I want to change parameters in my other userControls, I should go in  my Panel which is containing my UserControl, access to them with Panel.Controls, and change the bold parameter with that? I can't access to my UserControl simply, because they are dynamically added...

Comment: There are several ways to do this: you can just save references to those controls upon creation in `Page_Load` and then use them in click handling method OR you can acces them by `FindControl()` method. Either way you should assign unique ID to each of the control you create dynamically, so you can find it with `FindControl()` and allow asp.net to handle their viewstate properly (which may be needed).

Comment: Hmm ok. I thought it wasn't really a good way, but I believe you. So I don't have the explanation of why my solution didn't work, but your solution seem's working. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: See my answer for your question, I've explained there a bit why your solution did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information in the comments, I suppose that your solution does not work because you are recreating the controls in the `Click` event handling method, which is very late in the page's lifecycle and should not be used for adding controls.

As mentioned in the comments, I suggest you to create the controls in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` and **not** recreate them in the button's `Click` handling method. You should also assign a unique ID to each of them. Then, in the `Click` handler, you can use `FindControl` method to acces the created controls. Alternatively you can just save the references to the controls upon creation, so you can access them later easily.

Useful links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx
- http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/10/11/more-on-adding-controls-dynamically.aspx

Comment: I didn't use the `FindControl()` technique but used a `foreach()` on my UserControls' container to resolve my problem, because I have to make an action on every UserControls. But thanks for your help, now I understand why it didn't work :).